# Determine whether 4th character in cell is numeric or text

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to find a way to determine if the 4th character in a cell is either a letter or a number. I found a similar thread but their solution isn't working for me.

```
My example:
| A Column | B Column to return |
| -------- | -------------- |
| BKGB1000 | BKGB            |
| BKG41000 | BKG           |
```

`=IF(ISNUMBER((LEFT(A1,4))),LEFT(A1,3),LEFT(A1,4))`

I have also tried
`=IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A1&" ",4,1)),3,4)`

The above just isn't working. It keeps returning all 4 characters, so in the 2nd row it returns BKG4 instead of just BKG. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2,4,1)*1),"number","letter")`
The MID results in text. Multiplying it results in a number provided the character is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Solution. Thanks for the guidence P.b

`=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2&" ",4,1))),LEFT(A2,3),LEFT(A2,4))`